# What's the best tool to automatically organize or alphabetize your CSS properties?

Tags: css

I'm looking for a way to automatically organize (alphabetically, or by any other accepted "standard") all of my CSS properties. I would prefer a method in Dreamweaver, but I'll take anything at this point!

Example:

```
.div-name {
padding: 5px;
width: 300px;
margin: 10px;
color: #000;
}
```

would be converted to:

```
.div-name {
color: #000;
margin: 10px;
padding: 5px;
width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: that's not good, CSS stands for cascading style sheets, meaning that the order is important

Comment: Interesting question, never heard of such a tool! I know a good source code formatter but that doesn't sort the elements. @Eric he means ordering the properties themselves

Comment: He want to order the properies, not the selector declartions.

Comment: I just use a build tool we developed internally, among other things it helps you find stuff/duplicates/orders it./minify it and some then more  

I guess you can easily build a tool that simply splits it by { or }

Comment: Eric, the reason I suggested alphabetically is because that is how the browser interprets the properties (just dissect a page in Firebug and you'll see everything is ordered that way.) 

Nonetheless, if there is a better way of ordering the properties, that's fine! I just need some sort of tool that will standardize this throughout my stylesheet. It's very easy to get messy and out of order when you have 2,000+ lines.

Comment: @Joshua, yes that's interesting!

Comment: @Eric Fortis: The order of properties does not matter (unless you're talking IE hacks and `!important`).

Comment: @BoltClock don't forget browser-specific css. -moz & -webkit properties. Usually I do standard properties alphabetically followed by the non-standard properties (i.e. `border: 1px; margin: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;`)

Comment: @BoltClock What about stuff like `{background: #f00;background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);}`
Many cases make order important. Such algorithms should not sort multiple declarations of the same prop... That's the only limitation right?

Comment: @Armel Larcier: That's when Eric's comment about the cascade becomes relevant - the order of declarations becomes important when you're either dealing with the same property, or shorthands vs longhands. In this case, the properties are completely unrelated and no cascading is involved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

http://www.cleancss.com/

Haven't used it, but it appears to do what you say.

Bob

Comment: Someone updated the website and made the CSS formatter hard to find. Here's a direct link: https://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/

Answer (score 20):

There was formerly a tool called "CSScomb" (at csscomb.com) to sort and group your CSS. It had plugins for a wide variety of code editors.

Unfortunately, it is no longer online; the domain was for sale, and now it redirects to…something else.

There does appear to be an active repository here: https://github.com/csscomb/csscomb.js/

Comment: CSScomb plug-in for Gulp.js https://npmjs.org/package/gulp-csscomb

Answer (score 9):

I personally would not find this useful, but that's just me. I use my own hierarchy based on importance, and I keep this consistent throughout my stylesheets. Each person may have different preferences in regards to this. I personally like to do any *positional formatting* first, followed by *layout* parameters, then *sizing* and then *colors* and other *text formatting properties*.

This allows me to identify and edit the most important properties quickly, ones that may affect layout are to me the most important.

Here's a recap:

1.*positional formatting* such as `display`, `position` ... because this can affect the layout greatly

2.*layout* such as `margin` or `padding` ... same as above

3.*sizing* such as `width`, `height` or `font-size` ... this has the ability to affect layout.

4.*color* and *text formatting* such as `color`, `background-color`, `letter-spacing` or `text-transform`

Comment: Sure. That may be true. But I need a tool that organizes my properties, even if it's a custom-hierarchy. It's very cumbersome to organize thousands of properties by hand.

Comment: Also have the similar approach in my tools, however, I hardly imagine it being feasible (in terms of following it strictly) in a team with size of > 1 :)

Comment: @ArturBeljajev Absolutely true. This was in 2010 btw, when tools like LESS and SASS were young and slightly unwieldy. I'll consider publishing an edit.

Comment: @Sandwich How is that different now? How can I benefit from SASS to solve the issue in question? My knowledge in front-end is probably outdated.

Answer (score 1):

[CSSTidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/) is an executable and PHP script you can use to make formatting changes like this  (as well as optimizations). In fact, cleancss.com that [@rcravens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566414/whats-the-best-tool-to-automatically-organize-or-alphabetize-your-css-properties/4566454#4566454) mentioned is "based on" this tool.

Answer (score 1):

i use visual studio 2010, this extension allows you to comment css and alphabetize your css and some other pretty handy tools too

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f